# When trying to connect using sockets to printer using port 23 (telnet) i need to send an extra message to get what I want

Tags: java, sockets, printing, telnet

I'm programming a print Server and I want to know the status of the printer. The printer server hardware can be contated via telnet. to know printer status using telnet service i just need to put password that can be empty, and then choose option 1 and then option 2. So if I try to do this using java sockets I should do this:

```
        outToPrinter.println("");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
        outToPrinter.println("1");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
        outToPrinter.println("2");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
```

and buffer should come with the result that I want, but insted it comes with previous menu, like I've only pressed "" and "1", so to get the menu that I want I need to send one more message, like this:

```
        outToPrinter.println("");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
        outToPrinter.println("1");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
        outToPrinter.println("2");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
        outToPrinter.println("2");
        inFromPrinter.read(buf);
```

It actually works, I just wanted to know why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might need to `flush()` the `outToPrinter` stream, or instantiate it with `autoFlush`. What is your printer model?

Comment: That does not work. My printer model is Wasp WPL205

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a manual where the protocol is described, are the responses the same when you send `2` and read back?

Comment: I'm using the Tp-Link TL-PS110U print server, but yes when I send an extra message it answers what I want to

Comment: Are the two `inFromPrinter.read(buf);` after the same?

Comment: You're sending `2` and reading the result two times, do they give you the same message?

Comment: No, each option is like one menu behind the real menu. So I need an extra message to get the menu that I want.

Comment: I don't see the problem then, if you have to enter two different menu to get your result you have to send your choice two times.

Comment: Something like that. Well the important is that is working. Thank you for your help :)